# Puppeteer's temp directories in Heroku

Tags: heroku, puppeteer, temporary-files

I am using Puppeteer in Heroku and sometimes I get a strange error that the browser cannot be launched because of limited space which does not allow the creation of `/tmp/puppeteer_dev...` directory with `mkdtemp`.
This is really strange because this error happens only once and then definitely stops without my intervention. So it gives me the impression that a kind of redimentioning takes place behind the scenes as a reaction from Heroku.

Anyway, I am trying to locate where these `/tmp/puppeteer_dev` directories are located in heroku filesystem but I cannot really find anything. Normally they are located in `/tmp/` folder and they store information like browser storage, cookies, browser preferences, etc. I know that Heroku f/s is ephemeral but I would expect that at least during the execution of puppeteer a /tmp/subfolder would appear temporarily somewhere.
Any opinions?